# My loss is showing to be NaN and accuracy to be 0 when I'm training my LSTM model

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, lstm, loss

I'm trying to predict stock prices based on historical data. I'm using LSTM to train my model. But when I'm training, the loss is coming out to be NaN and accuracy to be 0. 
The data I'm using is from Yahoo Finance. 5 Years data of Yes Bank stock. I've split the data in test and train set and featured scaled it (although not required). Added 2 layers of LSTM to train.

My code is as follows:

````
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout


#Get the Data
data = pd.read_csv('YESBANK.NS.csv')
X = data.iloc[:, [5]].values

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test = train_test_split(X, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1))
training_set_scaled = sc.fit_transform(X_train)


# Creating a data structure with 60 timesteps and 1 output
X_train1 = []
y_train1 = []
for i in range(60, training_set_scaled.shape[0]):
    X_train1.append(training_set_scaled[i-60:i, 0])
    y_train1.append(training_set_scaled[i, 0])
X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train1), np.array(y_train1)

# Reshaping for LSTM 
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))


#Initialize the RNN
model = Sequential()

#Adding first LSTM layer
model.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

# #Adding second LSTM layer
# model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
# model.add(Dropout(0.2))

# #Adding third LSTM layer
# model.add(LSTM(units= 50, return_sequences=True))
# model.add(Dropout(0.2))

#Adding fourth LSTM layer
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

#Adding Output layer
model.add(Dense(units=1))

#Compiling the RNN
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics = ['accuracy'])

#Fitiing the RNN
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 500, batch_size = 10) ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your input data has `NaN`s in it.  If you're using [this data](https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/YESBANK.NS?period1=1553513982&period2=1585136382&interval=1d&events=history), then, at the time of writing, row 142 is entirely `NaN` except for the date column.  These will propagate through the scaling and cause the network to return `NaN`s.  A quick and resonable solution is to add this line after you read the data in:

```
data = data.fillna(data.mean())
```

A couple of additional points to note:

1. `pd.read_csv` can read from a URL directly.
2. Simply using `train_test_split` with `shuffle=True` for a time series problem is not ideal if you want to use the model for prediction.  The purpose of the test set is to act as if it's unseen data, which this arrangement doesn't satisfy.  You should consider splitting the data with `train` prior to a cutoff date and `test` after the cutoff date, as this would be more representative of the predictive situation (if that is your intent, and given the uninterpretable nature of neural networks, I assume it is).

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is `regression` to regress stock prices (i.e., continuous values). Therefore, you should not use `accuracy` as your `metric` function. You could either use mean squared error: 'mse' or mean absolute error: 'mae' as your metric function.